# Ruby on Rails 3: increment value using sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm doign a voting application and I need to update votes count for this I want to use update SQL, because in other cases voices may be lost (AR generates update statement with value, but what if previous request already incremented column value?).

Ho do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Movie.update_counters id, :like_count => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`increment_counter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html#method-i-increment_counter) which does a direct update in the database without caring about the actual value of your Active Record contents:

```
Vote.increment_counter :vote_value, 5
```